# Regular expression content generator

Tags: python, regex

As many questions here confirm, regular expressions are a common tool to process text: Find matching strings, extract values from configuration files and so on.

My question is: What is the best way, if it exist,  to **generate** contents matching a regular expression?

One example could be: From the regular expression: `[1-3]{2}` the method should generate a list, or more generally, a collection like:

```
"11"
"12"
"13"
"21"
"22"
"23"
"31"
"32"
"33"
```

I know how to make a program to do this, what I want to know is if does it exists a package, a class or a method to perform this task. Something like:

```
comp = re.compile("[1-3]{2}")
explorerIterator = comp.explore()
for s in explorerIterator:
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: You want to compute permutations

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes, for a given regular expression (not just the one above) calculate all possible permutations or a given number of them

Comment: Many regular expressions match an infinite number of strings, so there's not necessarily a useful way to generate them. If your pattern was `"[ab]*"`, you could just yield successively longer strings of all `'a'`s without ever a `'b'`. It might be more practical if you were limiting your regex a bit more (e.g. requiring a finite length).

Comment: @SimonKuang Of course. I wonder if `re` provides a short way of doing it.

Comment: @Pablo That was a joke. I don't actually know Python.

Comment: @Blckknght Exactly, I had in mind a tool providing an interface as iterator or methods like `hasNext()` and `next()` so you could stop asking for new strings at any time. No need to explore all the language matching the regular expression.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo: I guess my point is that the order you get the matching strings may matter a lot. For the pattern I suggested, it is probably a lot nicer to get `"a", "b", "aa", "ab", "ba", ...` than it is to get `"a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", ...`.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, it is is bread-first versus depth-first exploration. As you point, the best in this case is bread-first exploration.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo **breadth**-first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a module written by asciimoo called [exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex), that can do that. Have a look at that.

Here is a nice example taken from that page:

```
>>> list(exrex.generate('((hai){2}|world!)'))
['haihai', 'world!']
```